# When pulling data from Database via SSRA how to automatically Hyperlink the field?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, report

I am making a SSRS report. I am trying to pull the Data in such a way that if the Field (which I am pulling in the report) is a Hyperlink then it will show as a active Hyperlink in the Report page.

I am pulling Data from VarChar and I have that Column with some Data like "This is a Column with http://www.stackoverflow.com which should be active in the Reportpage".

I was thinking that any hyperlink should automatically be active in any browser, but its not.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Select Cell value>Right Click>Click Properties>Select Action on left pane>select 'Go to Url'>Under 'Select URL:' ensure your column with the correct varchar link location is used.

Comment: I am not trying to give Hyperlink to the whole thing. Hyperlink to only the URLs. These url(with the whole paragraph) are coming in the table as input from a different application. So these cannot be static to any hyperlink but has to be dynamic as entered by users.

Comment: It will know which are valid links and which are not in my experience.